# How to use prototypal inheritance?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var o = {
    prototype: {
        foo: function(){console.log('bar');}
    }
}
```

My understanding is that when I do `Object.create(o)` the returned object should have a method `.foo`.

However, what if I also attach a create method to `o`?

```
var o = {
    prototype: {
        foo: function(){console.log('bar');}
    },
    create: function(){}
}
```

Does the prototypal magic of javascript do something different in this case?

Comment: Check out https://skimmable-videos.herokuapp.com/show/558f4dc9c240320300d8ef34

Comment: No, you would have to do `Object.create(o.prototype)`. `prototype` is meaningless there, too, since `o` isn’t a function.

Comment: `prototype` has no meaning on regular objects. Only on functions (where it's included by default). In your `Object.create(o)`, you'll get back an empty object that *inherits* from the `o` object, so you can implicitly look up properties that exist on `o`, like your `prototype` property and by extension its `foo` property. `var x = Object.create(o); x.prototype.foo();`. And again, `prototype` is just an ordinary property here. It could be any valid property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is incorrect. You would have to do something like this:

```
var o = {
    __proto__: {
        foo: function() {
            console.log('bar');
        }
    }
};
```

so that the object returned from `Object.create(o)` would have the foo method.

```
var o2 = Object.create(o);
o2.foo(); // prints bar
```

Modern browsers have implemented the `__proto__` as a way of accessing the internal `[[Prototype]]` chain of an object. It is not actually in the standard and it's direct use is discouraged and may even lead to suboptimal code due to possible optimizations done by the browser on the `__proto__` property.

In the example above the `__proto__` fakes the internal representation of the prototype chain to demonstrate that `Object.create` connects the internal `[[Prototype]]`, i.e. the `__proto__` property.

The .prototype property which is on all function objects, for example:

```
var o = function() {};
typeof o.prototype  // returns "object"
```

Is used by the new operator in order to populate the internal `[[Prototype]]` (ie the `__proto__` property) and build that instances prototype chain.

If you did the following

```
var o = {
    __proto__: {
        foo: function() {
            console.log('bar');
        }
    }, 
    create: function() {},
};

o2 = Object.create(o);
```

o2 would have both methods except they would be on different levels of the prototype chain, something like:

```
{ 
  __proto__: {
     create: function() { ... },
     __proto__: {
        foo: function() { ... }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prototype is just a property that points on constructor function. In JS, you can add properties dynamically on any objects. If you want to add properties in a class (I mean all objects which is an instance of that class), you must add properties to its prototype.